# How to parse date and time with Date.strptime

Tags: ruby, date, parsing, time

If I use `Date#strptime` to parse an Exif date like `2017:03:11 18:02:30` the time is ignored:

```
Date.strptime("2017:03:11 18:02:30", '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
=> "2017:03:11 00:00:00"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date` doesn't contain information about the exact time, use `DateTime` instead:

```
DateTime.strptime("2017:03:11 18:02:30", '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
=> "2017:03:11 18:02:30"
```